# Beautifulsoup Unable to Find Classes with Hyphens in Their Name

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using BeautifulSoup4 on a MacOSX running Python 2.7.8. I am having difficulty extracting information from the following html code

```
 <tbody tabindex="0" class="yui-dt-data" id="yui_3_5_0_1_1408418470185_1650">
      <tr id="yui-rec0" class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-even">
           <td headers="yui-dt0-th-rank" class="rank yui-dt0-col-rank"></td>
           </tr>
      <tr id="yui-rec1" class="yui-dt-odd">...</tr>
      <tr id="yui-rec2" class="yui-dt-even">...</tr>
 </tbody>
```

I can't seem to grab the table or any of it's contents because BS and/or python doesn't seem to recognize values with hyphens. So the usual code, something like

```
 Table = soup.find('tbody',{'class':'yui-dt-data'})
```

or

```
 Row2 = Table.find('tr',{'id':'yui-rec2'})
```

just returns an empty object (not NONE, simply empty). I'm not new to BS4 or Python and I've extracted information from this site before, but the class names are different now than when I previously did it. Now everything has hyphens. Is there any way to get Python to recognize the hyphen or a workaround?

I need to have my code be general so that I can run it across numerous pages that all have the same class name. Unfortunately, the `id` attribute in `<tbody>` is unique to that particular table, so I can't use that to identify this table across webpages.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is it possible that the HTML is badly formed?

Answer (score 6):

The following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlstring = """ <tbody tabindex="0" class="yui-dt-data" id="yui_3_5_0_1_1408418470185_1650">
      <tr id="yui-rec0" class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-even">
      <tr id="yui-rec1" class="yui-dt-odd">
      <tr id="yui-rec2" class="yui-dt-even">"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlstring)
Table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'yui-dt-data'}) 
print("Table:\n")
print(Table)
tr = Table.find('tr', attrs={'class': 'yui-dt-odd'}) 
print("tr:\n")
print(tr)
```

outputs:

```
Table:

<tbody class="yui-dt-data" id="yui_3_5_0_1_1408418470185_1650" tabindex="0">
<tr class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-even" id="yui-rec0">
<tr class="yui-dt-odd" id="yui-rec1">
<tr class="yui-dt-even" id="yui-rec2"></tr></tr></tr></tbody>
tr:

<tr class="yui-dt-odd" id="yui-rec1">
<tr class="yui-dt-even" id="yui-rec2"></tr></tr>
```

Even though the html you supplied isn't by itself valid, it seems that BS is making a guess about how it should be, because `soup.prettify()` yields

```
<tbody class="yui-dt-data" id="yui_3_5_0_1_1408418470185_1650" tabindex="0">
 <tr class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-even" id="yui-rec0">
  <tr class="yui-dt-odd" id="yui-rec1">
   <tr class="yui-dt-even" id="yui-rec2">
   </tr>
  </tr>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Though I'm guessing those tr's aren't supposed to be nested.

Could you try running that exact code and seeing what the output is?

Comment: The code you have works fine for me. I looked in detail at the soup output in my code and it looks like BS is dropping or making a guess for attributes that have dashes in the name. For instance, the `<tbody>` tag is parsed without any of it's attributes following it while, for example, the second `<tr>` tag is parsed `<tr class="odd">` where the previous words have been stripped from the class name and the `id` attribute doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 6):

For people trying to find a solution to find a tag with hyphen in its attributes, there is an answer in the document
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments

This segment of code will cause error

```py
data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>')
data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value")
# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

you should do this

```py
data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
# [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `select`. bs4 4.7.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<tbody tabindex="0" class="yui-dt-data" id="yui_3_5_0_1_1408418470185_1650">
      <tr id="yui-rec0" class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-even">
           <td headers="yui-dt0-th-rank" class="rank yui-dt0-col-rank"></td>
           </tr>
      <tr id="yui-rec1" class="yui-dt-odd">...</tr>
      <tr id="yui-rec2" class="yui-dt-even">...</tr>
 </tbody>
 '''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
soup.select('.yui-dt-data')
```